# gradle jenkins pipeline with codecov

Tags: jenkins, code-coverage

I have a pipeline job for Spring and gradle:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        pollSCM '* * * * *'
    }
    tools {
        jdk 'jdk-16'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'java -version'
                sh "chmod +x gradlew"
                sh './gradlew assemble'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'java -version'
                sh "chmod +x gradlew"
                sh './gradlew test'
            }
        }
       stage('Publish Test Coverage Report') {
         steps {
           step([$class: 'JacocoPublisher',
                execPattern: '**/build/jacoco/*.exec',
                classPattern: '**/build/classes',
                sourcePattern: 'src/main/java',
                exclusionPattern: 'src/test*'
                ])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am uploading the coverage it is available on the jenkins server, but I also want to upload it to codecov on the codecov page for jenkins and java there is a guide for freestyle job: https://about.codecov.io/blog/how-to-set-up-codecov-with-java-and-jenkins/

```
name: Jenkins CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'adopt'
    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew clean build

  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Run tests
        run:  ./gradlew clean build
      - name: Coverage Report
        run:  ./gradlew jacocoTestReport
      - name: Upload coverage to Codecov
        uses: codecov/codecov-action@v1
        with:
          fail_ci_if_error: false
```

How can I integrate this in my pipline flow instead of a jenkins.yml file?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding codecov commands to the Publish Test Coverage Report stage:

```
sh 'curl -Os https://uploader.codecov.io/latest/linux/codecov'
sh 'chmod +x codecov'
sh './codecov -t ${token}'
```

The Report Stage:

```
stage('Publish Test Coverage Report') {
    steps {
        step([$class: 'JacocoPublisher',
            execPattern: '**/build/jacoco/*.exec',
            classPattern: '**/build/classes',
            sourcePattern: 'src/main/java',
            exclusionPattern: 'src/test*'
        ])
        sh 'curl -Os https://uploader.codecov.io/latest/linux/codecov'
        sh 'chmod +x codecov'
        sh './codecov -t ${TOKEN}'
    }
}
```

It is the new beta Uploader that is replacing the deprecating bash. Commands for other OS: https://about.codecov.io/blog/introducing-codecovs-new-uploader/